# Python os.popen error wxPython

Tags: python, compilation, dllimport

I created a executable with py2exe for a wxpython app what working fine, when starting the executable created gives me an error about os.popen. code that creates the executable is:

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(name="GridSimple",scripts=["GridSimple.py"],)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Sj8.jpg

Here about this problem http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingStandaloneExecutables?highlight=%28unicows.dll%29#py2exe
They say "include the file unicows.dll" Where is it?